# Can I activate Keegan Lane via Acme Consulting ability?

Tags: android-netrunner

Can I activate [Keegan Lane](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09024) (trash+"virtual" tag removal) during the runner's encounter with the outermost piece of ice if the id is [Acme Consulting](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/22042)? The runner has no tags before the run and the ice does not give them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
From ANCUR UFAQ [Michael Boggs]:

> Can the additional tag from Acme Consulting be removed?
>
> No. The Runner is considered to have an additional tag during
>   encounters with outermost ice, even when they have none, but it does
>   not exist for the purposes of being manipulated (such as removing it).